# Java code structuring for school project

Tags: java

Myself and 3-4 students in my Java class current are working on a project and none of us agree on a way in which to do specific part.

For context here's the directions for this part:

- A card ID which should be a whole number
- A name which should be text
- A set of 8 permissions, each of these 8 permission will represent one door. This could be stored as booleans, integers or whatever you like.
- You must also make the following method available:

  > `public boolean checkDoorPermissions(int doorNumber)`
  >
  > behavior: This method will take an integer from 0 to 7 representing one of 8 doors. It will return true if this card's owner (this object) should open the door numbered doorNumber. The method should return false otherwise.

We are at odds over how to go about the permissions. I've suggested an array list as it may be easier to access it in the method afterwards. Others have suggested making 8 `boolean` permissions, or 8 `int`s (e.g. `private int doorNumber8;`).

Any help/direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not a simple array ?

Comment: Why don't you use an Enum with 8 items?

Comment: Use an array of boolean (for clarity). Actually, a single byte is sufficient, but the code will be dirty.

Comment: What is a card ID? How is that relevant to your question? Note that you are probably supposed to figure this out on your own because it is a good exercise. It borders on cheating to ask here.

Comment: I agree with nhahtdh. Please don't go down the 'using each bit of a single byte' route. Just because there are eight doors CURRENTLY, it shouldn't be an invite to cram your data into a byte just because it happens to have eight bits. My response as a tutor would then be: "Oh, very clever. But now I want 14 doors..."

Comment: Sadly last semester Enums were completely skipped. Been giving myself a crash-course on them all week, not enough to use them right now though. including what was being asked of was just a way of having context of where we are coming from with our question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to give code because this seems like an assignment, but you could create a `Door` class in which there was a `String name`, `int id`, and `boolean permission`.

Then, create 8 `Door`s and store them in an array.

Here's something to get you started:

```
class Door {
    boolean permission;
    String name;
    int id;
    public Door(boolean permission, String name, int id) {
        //initialize your variables here!
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did the name of doors come from? Why do we need to store the id in the object when it's also key in the array? Isn't this an overly convoluted way for mapping integers to booleans?

Comment: @EmilVikström Read the question again.

Comment: I tried to understand the question but it is unclear. I think the assignment is to represent a key card, so the name and id is for the card.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only eight doors, and the permission is either "yes" or "no", you can simply make an eight bit character string, with `1` representing permission. You could then define

```
DOOR0 = 1;
DOOR1 = 2;
DOOR2 = 4;
DOOR3 = 8;
```

etc. - and a user's permission would be something like

```
userPermission = DOOR1 + DOOR4 + DOOR7;
```

Then you test a user's permission with

```
if(userPermission & DOOR5) {
  // permission granted
}
```

The number 8 in  the question just BEGS the use of a byte for storing the data...

And if you need to be able to test to a variable door number `doorNum`, your test becomes

```
if(userPermission & (1 << doorNum) {
```

which will shift the number `1` to the appropriate location (note - I just re-read the question and realized your doors are numbered base0; I edited the answer accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

As you've found in class this question will solicit various answers.  Personally I think the clearest would be to use a `java.util.Set` that contains the ids of the accessible doors.

This would result in:

```
public boolean checkDoorPermissions(int doorNumber)
{
  return accessibleDoorNumbers.contains(doorNumber);
}
```

It's simple and allows class implementing the `checkDoorPermissions` method to be used with varying numbers of doors.

Comment: ...another solution should be using a Map<Integer,Boolean> in order to set the permission to each door

Answer (score 0):

I would define a Door enum with eight possible values: DOOR1, DOOR2, etc.
Each person would then have a "collection" which contains between zero and eight of those enum values. (I say collection rather than ArrayList... have a look at the EnumSet class).

Try not to be too clever. Using bitmasks, etc. might initially seem very impressive. But your code will be confusing and unreadable, especially for an academic task. 
Remember rule one of software development: Keep It Simple!

Answer (score -1):

Define an enum would be more readable:

```
public Enum Doors {
    DOOR1
    ,DOOR2
    ,DOOR3
    ,DOOR4
    ,DOOR5
    ,DOOR6
    ,DOOR7
    ,DOOR8
}
```

However, you can manage with simple byte array and masking operations:

```
byte[] doors = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07};
```

Then in order to check which permissions are set you do something like:

```
(byte) b & doors[i]; // 1 = 0...7
```